# XlsxWriter how to create a border that is only at the top of a line chart plotarea?

Tags: python-3.x, xlsxwriter

Is it possibel to plot a border that is only on the top of a line chart? I used               chart.set_plotarea({'border': {'color': 'red', 'width': 2}}). But this obviously create a border around the whole plot area. How to format the border, that it s only at the top of the chart?

Comment: Is that possible in Excel?